# Why the data from firebase database deleting automatically?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Real-time database for one of my application. I used to store some key data in the database. but the database deleting the data automatically. why?

Comment: Can you place some of your code here so we can have a clue on what's going on?

Comment: can you show the code because in firebase data does not delete automatically, you should be doing something wrong

Comment: mFireBaseDatabase   =   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mdatabaseUsers      = mFireBaseDatabase.getReference("macIds");

Comment: if (macId == null && macId.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please check Intenet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {

            UserMACData data    =   new UserMACData(macId,status,deviceId);

            mdatabaseUsers.child(deviceId).setValue(data);

//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: Please add the code *to your question*. This is the comments section and not for long pieces of code as it's difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

there are possible reasons of "why" data was deleted, please check them:

1. Security rules in the firebase DB may be set to allow to anyone write (and delete) the data. So the data may be deleted mistakenly by some user.
2. If need to append the data - using of setValue() instead of .push().setValue()  - will override rather then append

   In case it was not helpful - please provide more details.